# Android Studio UI PNG image overlayering a map

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Im attempting to add a camera symbol at the bottom of my application (Like Snapchat) overlayering a map, but cant seem to make it work. The layer and the imagebutton within places itself below the layer containing the map object. If i reduce the hight of the "map-layer" it works, but then there is, naturaly, a white void on either side of the camera symbol which is centered.

Any suggestions? Here is a picture and the layout file, i included the whole thing in case i made some mistakes early on that causes the issue. All help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#165d38">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:src="@drawable/mark"
                android:background="#00000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swoop"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|right" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/mr_ic_settings_light"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment tools:context="net.net16.swooptest.demomaps.MapsActivity"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="#00000000">

//THIS IS THE CAMERA BUTTON
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android:elevation property so button will be above map in relative layout